# Rxjs combine omitted observables into an array

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have the following code that assembles items to display in a NavBar.

For some items, it calls an API to fetch extra info and adds that information to the `subtitle` field.

I would like to recombine this into an `Observable<NavItem[]>` so it can be rendered using an Async Pipe.

Currently it logs each `NavItem` before I call `ops.toArray()`. But the log call after `ops.toArray()` never returns...

Is there a better RXJS way to recombine these items into a `Observable<NavItem[]>` ?

```js
import * as ops from 'rxjs/operators';

navItem$: Observable<NavItem[]> = null

this.navItem$ = this.store.pipe(
  select(fromRoute.selectLastUrls),
  ops.map((d) => {
    // Initial construction of NavItems
  }),
  ops.tap((i) => console.log(i)), // Prints an array of 5 NavItems as expected
  ops.mergeAll(),
  ops.mergeMap((i) =>
    iif(
      () => i.listItem,
      // Call the API for some list items (To add subtitle detail)
      this.backendService.find({ title: [i.title] }).pipe(
        ops.map((found) => ({...i, subtitle: found.items[0].info,})),),
        of(i),
    ),
  ),
  ops.tap((i) => console.log(i)), // This expected 1 NavItem per log line (with data appended from the API calls)
  ops.toArray(),
  ops.tap((i) => console.log(i)) // This line never logs
);
```

Comment: instead of `mergeAll` you'd better `switchMap((arr) => from(arr).pipe(...,toArray()))`. then toArray would be applied to this group only instead

Comment: @Andrei thanks, your solution worked well. Please post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your case `toArray` waits for the whole stream to complete, and then it would gather all of the elements as one single array.

to apply this logic only to group instead, you will have to put operators on one level deeper. like this:

```
this.navItem$ = this.store.pipe(
  select(fromRoute.selectLastUrls),
  ops.map((d) => {
    // Initial construction of NavItems
  }),
  ops.tap((i) => console.log(i)), // Prints an array of 5 NavItems as expected
  ops.switchMap(arr => from(arr).pipe(
     ops.mergeMap((i) =>
       iif(
        () => i.listItem,
         // Call the API for some list items (To add subtitle detail)
         this.backendService.find({ title: [i.title] }).pipe(
           ops.map((found) => ({...i, subtitle: found.items[0].info,})),),
         of(i),
       ),
     ),
     ops.tap((i) => console.log(i)), // This expected 1 NavItem per log line (with data appended from the API calls)
     ops.toArray(),
    ))
  
  ops.tap((i) => console.log(i)) // This line will log arrays now
);
```

I would also mention that it is not recommended to `import * as ops from 'rxjs/operators';` as this way all of the oprerators will get into the bundle. If you just import every operator independently then all of the unused ones could be tree shaked away and the bundle should be smaller as a result